# Generating a Sparse Matrix in C

Tags: c, random, sparse-matrix

Is there a simpler way of generating  sparse matrix other than this?

```
for (i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
{
    if (rand() % 3 == 0)
    {
        array[i] = rand() % 3;
    }
    else
    {
        array[i] = ((rand() % 3) - 1);
    }
}
```

Thanks.

I used array for presentational purposes

Comment: It doesn't look like a matrix or sparse to me. You have a *vector* (1D array) for which around a third of the elements are zero - is that what you are really trying to achieve ?

Comment: As I said, I used an array for presentational purposes. And no, I'm trying to make it more sparse without spaghetti code. So I came here to ask for help

Comment: I hope you realize that calling `rand()` in the if/else clauses is giving you a different random number than the one which put you into that case?

Comment: What about: starting with a zero matrix, given a sparsity, generate random, non-zero elements and shuffle the matrix?

Comment: @JosuéMolina Save the shuffle, start with a zero matrix and put non-zero elements into randomly selected locations up 'til the sparsity level desired.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let `t` be the target number of non-zero elements in the array, which should be much less than the length of the array for sparseness.  I'm assuming your array is of length `length`.  I'm also generating the random indices without the modulus operator to avoid modulo bias.

```
for (i = 0; i < t; ++i) {
   int index = (int) (length * ((double) rand() / (RAND_MAX + 1.0)));
   array[index] = i % 2 ? -1 : 1;
}
```

Note that this may give a few less than `t` non-zero elements because random numbers can produce duplicates, but that should be rare if it really is sparse, e.g., `t` < square root of the array length.  If you're worried about duplicate randoms making things sparser than you want, you can modify accordingly:

```
for (i = 0; i < t;) {
   int index = (int) (length * ((double) rand() / (RAND_MAX + 1.0)));
   if (array[index]) {  /* something already at this index */
      continue;         /* skip incrementing and try again */
   }
   array[index] = i % 2 ? -1 : 1;
   ++i;
}
```

In both cases I'm alternating +/- ones for the non-zero values, but if you want it more random that would be easy to replace the right-hand side of the assignment of `array[index]`.

Finally, I ask your indulgence if I fluffed something on C syntax. My C is about 15 years rusty, but the intent should be clear.

Comment: The only limitation is that it is bounded by RAND_MAX size and may not be suitable for generating large sets of random numbers.

Answer (score 3):

With `a` determine how sparse you want it to be.

```
for (i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
{
    if (rand() % a == 0)
    {
        array[i] = rand() % 100;
    }
    else
    {
        array[i] = 0;
    }
}
```